# VBS as LocalSystem in RDP

Tags: vbscript, rdp, local-system-account

Using PSEXEC and to run a VBS as LocalSystem account, to let the script run with admin rights.
VB script called prompts and GUIs are not visible if a person is connected to the computer via RDP.

You can see the script or GUI as a running process in task manager, but it is not visible.

Windows Security setting preventing this? Limitation of RDP?

Answer (score 0):

Your script is running in an invisible desktop so you cannot run a denial of service attack on the interactive user of the physical computer.

This is normal.

State what your goal is rather than why your solution to an unknown problem doesn't work.

It doesn't matter your intentions.

This question is better suited to https://serverfault.com as you are trying to administer a network by programming rather than how it's designed to be administered.

Normally one uses logon scripts or group policy to set the RunOnce key.

Comment: HA! It isn't a DoS attack. I am running and HTA page to install a software package. Users do not have admin rights, so we are simply pushing a VBS to PCs as the Local System account, so it runs with admin rights, then the user can click install when they are ready. The GUI is ONLY hidden when a user is connected via RDP, sitting at a monitor or using another remote desktop app (Dameware) it is perfectly visible.

Comment: After more research this has to do with the GUI running in the Console Session with the Users RDP running in a higher Session ID. So there might not be a solution.

Comment: The interactive user **can** reboot the computer kicking off remote ones.